# Showing marker on address of the users on google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using Google maps JavaScript API, i get users zip code from database, find lang, lat for it from another table, pass it to JavaScript and show marker on the map.this is showing marker perfectly.
But i want to show marker on exact address of the user instead of  just zip code.
But unable to find a way how to do this.

Can anybody please guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: do you want to place the marker on given lat and lng?

Comment: The same process you are using to get the latitude and longitude for the zip code should work if you pass in the complete address.  You haven't provided the code you use, so can't be certain.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to place the marker on given lat and lng use this code,

```
use this code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
html, body, #map-canvas {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
 }
</style>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
  <script>
   var map;
  var markersArray=[];
   function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(11.6667,76.2667),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
 }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function pan() {
deleteOverlays();
    var panPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("lat").value,     document.getElementById("lng").value);
    map.setCenter(panPoint)
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: panPoint,
        });
        markersArray.push(marker);

 }

 function deleteOverlays() {
   if (markersArray) {
      for (i in markersArray) {
       markersArray[i].setMap(null);
      }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
Latitude:<input type="text" id="lat" >
Longitude:<input type="text" id="lng">
<input type="button" value="updateCenter" onclick="pan()" />


<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```